# StatusCheckFailed Cloud Watch Alarm for Auto Scaling Group remains in INSUFFICIENT_DATA after being created with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform

I am trying to add a Cloud Watch Alarm to an existing Auto Scaling group.  After running terraform apply, I can see the alarm listed under the CloudWatch section of the AWS console.  However, the alarm's state will stay in `INSUFFICIENT_DATA`.

State Details contains the message `State changed to INSUFFICIENT_DATA at 2016/04/19. Reason: Unchecked: Initial alarm creation`

The terraform resource that I've used to create the alarm is below:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "dwalters_status_check_failed" {
    alarm_name = "dWaltersStatusCheckFailedTest"
    alarm_description = "Test if alarm goes from INSUFFICIENT_DATE -> OK after being initialized"
    comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
    dimensions = {
      AutoscalingGroupName = "test-autoscaling-group"
    }
    evaluation_periods = "1"
    metric_name = "StatusCheckFailed"
    namespace = "AWS/EC2"
    period = "300"
    statistic = "Maximum"
    threshold = "1"
    unit = "Count"
    alarm_actions = []
}
```

Even though the metric and Auto Scaling Group that are listed in the alarm exist, I have to select the alarm, click `Modify`, reselect the same metric and Auto Scaling Group, and click 'Save' in order to change the state from `INSUFFICIENT_DATA` to `OK`.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: Can you also post the TF section that's creating your autoscaling group. I think Terraform might be creating the ASG after it's creating the CloudWatch metric, which might be the problem.

Comment: similar issue ,investigating will keep the thread posted

Comment: You have to pay careful attention to the dimensions. The keys and values are case-sensitive. That is probably why your alarm is not triggered. It cannot match the right metric...

Answer (score 2):

With my experience, the `dimensions` part is the problem.

Suppose you did all in terraform, the `AutoscalingGroupName` shouldn't be hard coded.

```
dimensions = {
  AutoscalingGroupName = "test-autoscaling-group"
}
```

Could you change to

```
dimensions = {
  AutoscalingGroupName = "${aws_autoscaling_group.bar.name}"
}
```

You need to adjust the resource name, depend on how you define the scaling group.